# Simple Recursion Equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Starting with C1 = 3, C2 = -2, and C3 = -1, I need to write a code where it follows the formula of:

```
thenextanswer = thelatestanswer + (2 * thesecondanswerback) - (3 * thethirdanswerback)
```

to help make it easier to understand I wrote it out in simple terms:

```
C4 = C3 + 2*C2 - 3*C1
C5 = C4 + 2*C3 - 3*C2
C6 = C5 + 2*C4 - 3*C3
C7 = C6 + 2*C5 - 3*C4
C8 = C7 + 2*C6 - 3*C5
```

and so on, all the way until C55

I have the math of how to do all the recursive answers done, I'm just having trouble putting it into python and having python calculate it. This is my code so far (pretty much just guess work and jotting down basic ideas): http://prntscr.com/nbigl5

Any tips/tricks of how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Why would you use recursion for this? Is that some kind of external requirement (e.g. homework assignment)? The very fact that you yourself, quite reasonably, use variables external to the function to maintain state suggests that recursion is not at all a natural way to do this. Just looping would be the obvious way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be better if you would put the code inside the question (formatted with the toolbutton), instead of linking an image.

Comment: yes recursion is required for this for the homework. i have the correct answers using islice already.

Comment: Your explanation above has `C2 = -2` but your link to your jotting down ideas has `C2 =  2`.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is necessarily recursion, it just looks like an open-form expression

```
c = [3, -2, -1]
for i in range(3,55): # index starts at 0, 3 <= i < 55
    c.append(c[i-1] + (2*c[i-2]) - (3*c[i-3]))
```

If it needs to be recursion you could do something like

```
def calculate(n):
    if n == 1:
        c[n] = 3
    elif n == 2:
        c[n] = -2
    elif n == 3:
        c[n] = -1
    else:
        if n-3 in c.keys():
            z = c[n-3]
        else:
            z = calculate(n-3)
        if n-2 in c.keys():
            y = c[n-2]
        else:
            y = calculate(n-2)
        if n-1 in c.keys():
            x = c[n-1]
        else:
            x = calculate(n-1)
        c[n] = x + 2*y - 3*z
    return c[n]

c = {}
calculate(55)
print(c)
```

which gives output:

```
{1: 3, 2: -2, 3: -1, 4: -14, 5: -10, 6: -35, 7: -13, 8: -53, 9: 26, 10: -41, 11: 170, 12: 10, 13: 473, 14: -17, 15: 899, 16: -554, 17: 1295, 18: -2510, 19: 1742, 20: -7163, 21: 3851, 22: -15701, 23: 13490, 24: -29465, 25: 44618, 26: -54782, 27: 122849, 28: -120569, 29: 289475, 30: -320210, 31: 620447, 32: -888398, 33: 1313126, 34: -2325011, 35: 2966435, 36: -5622965, 37: 7284938, 38: -12860297, 39: 18578474, 40: -28996934, 41: 46740905, 42: -66988385, 43: 113484227, 44: -160715258, 45: 267218351, 46: -394664846, 47: 621917630, 48: -969067115, 49: 1458762683, 50: -2345124437, 51: 3479602274, 52: -5586934649, 53: 8407643210, 54: -13205032910, 55: 20371057457}
```

EDIT:
Function to do true recursion (based off of iElden's answer below, but I wasn't getting the right results when I ran it, but I made some changes and it is a lot more efficient than what I came up with)

```
def calc(c3, c2, c1, n, maxn):
    result = c3 + 2*c2 - 3*c1
    print("n: "+str(n)+" r: "+str(result))
    if n == maxn:
        return result
    else:
        return calc(result, c3, c2, n + 1, maxn)
calc(-1, -2, 3, 4, 20)
```

And my true recursion, which takes a long time to compute but gets the right answers and is more true to the spirit of recursion in my opinion

```
def recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        r = 3
    elif n == 2:
        r = -2
    elif n == 3:
        r = -1
    else:
        z = recursive(n-3)
        y = recursive(n-2)
        x = recursive(n-1)
        r = x + 2*y - 3*z
    print("n: "+str(n)+" r: "+str(r))
    return r
recursive(20)
```

Output through C20:

```
n: 4 r: -14
n: 5 r: -10
n: 6 r: -35
n: 7 r: -13
n: 8 r: -53
n: 9 r: 26
n: 10 r: -41
n: 11 r: 170
n: 12 r: 10
n: 13 r: 473
n: 14 r: -17
n: 15 r: 899
n: 16 r: -554
n: 17 r: 1295
n: 18 r: -2510
n: 19 r: 1742
n: 20 r: -7163
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this is recursion, because it's supposed to take a long time to calculate because it keeps having to check back at the past results. my teacher said it would slow down or take hours to complete calculating them all if it was done with the right way of recursion we're learning. it gives all the right answers though, this is confusing. i got the same answers using splice

Comment: Edited my answer to not rely on a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing to do when you want make a recursive function is to define the stopping condition.
Here, the stopping condition is when your result is C55, i named this variable `loop_nb`

Then you have to look at what you want to transmit between each step, here, you want to transmit your result and the first two parameters.

In code it gives that :

```
def calc(c3, c2, c1, loop_nb):
    result = c3 + 2*c2 - 3*c1
    if loop_nb == 55:
        return result
    else:
        return calc(result, c3, c2, loop_nb + 1)


calc(-1, -2, 3, 4)
```

I hope it has been useful for your homework !

Comment: Your invocation of your function doesn't match the OP's constants and probably should instead be `calc(-1, -2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer, and summarize existing answers, we can use a simple, and reasonably quick recursion a la @iElden (+1) and @MatthewK (+1) by doing something like:

```
def simply_recursive(c1, c2, c3, n=55):
    c4 = c3 + 2 * c2 - 3 * c1

    if n == 4:
        return c4

    return simply_recursive(c2, c3, c4, n - 1)

print(simply_recursive(3, -2, -1))  # 20371057457
```

Or we can take a slower solution with multiple recursions a la @MatthewK and speed it up using a cache to optimize redundant calls:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def massively_recursive(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 3

    if n == 2:
        return -2

    if n == 3:
        return -1

    c1 = massively_recursive(n - 3)
    c2 = massively_recursive(n - 2)
    c3 = massively_recursive(n - 1)

    return c3 + 2 * c2 - 3 * c1

print(massively_recursive(55))  # 20371057457
```

Both of which will have roughly the same performance:

```
> time python3 test1.py
20371057457
0.029u 0.006s 0:00.04 50.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
> time python3 test2.py
20371057457
0.027u 0.006s 0:00.04 50.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
>
```